# Sending ESXI audit logs to http endpoint?

Tags: vmware-esxi, syslog, vmware-vcenter

Is it possible to send audit logs from ESXI's (or better yet, vCenter) to an http endpoint via API/webhook rather than a syslog server?
Couldnt find a direct answer or a tutorial online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Both ESXi and vCenter only support syslog.